# PySide, QTextEdit Append adding blank lines

Tags: python-2.7, append, pyside, qtextedit, qprocess

I have this simple code: basically a tool to send some commands to cmd, and display the output from cmd in a QTextEdit.
Basically, it works.
The only problem that I have is that each time I click on send (with or without a new command), the text is appended but strange blank lines appears at the end of the QTextEdit. Even when i clear the "console", still have these lines.
Maybe it has something to do with the way I call the process, I don't know hence the need for help.

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
import sys


class MyWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle("Send to CMD")

        self.check1 = QCheckBox("Activate Variable")
        self.variable = QLineEdit()
        self.finalcommand = QLineEdit()
        self.clearCommand = QPushButton("Clear")
        self.sendCommand = QPushButton("Send")
        self.clearOnSend = QCheckBox("Clear on Send")

        self.process = QProcess()
        self.console = QTextEdit(self)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.check1)
        layout.addWidget(self.variable)
        layout.addWidget(self.finalcommand)
        layout.addWidget(self.clearOnSend)
        layout.addWidget(self.clearCommand)
        layout.addWidget(self.sendCommand)
        layout.addWidget(self.console)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.connect(self.check1, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.appendText)
        self.variable.textChanged.connect(self.appendText)

        self.clearCommand.clicked.connect(self.Clear)
        self.sendCommand.clicked.connect(self.Send)

    def appendText(self):
        if self.check1.isChecked():
            TEXT1 = "Dir" + ' ' + str(self.variable.text())
        else:
            TEXT1 = ""
        self.finalcommand.setText(str(TEXT1))

    def Clear(self):
        if self.clearCommand.isEnabled():
            self.console.clear()

    def Send(self):
        if self.clearOnSend.isChecked():
            self.console.clear()
        FCTS = "cmd.exe /c" + " " + str(self.finalcommand.text())
        self.process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.readConsole)
        self.process.start(FCTS)
        if not self.process.waitForStarted(0):
            return False
        if not self.process.waitForFinished(0):
            return False

    def readConsole(self):
        #self.console.setText(str(self.process.readAllStandardOutput()))
        self.console.append(str(self.process.readAllStandardOutput()))



app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = MyWindow()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: maybe try 
def readConsole(self):
    Ba = self.process.readAllStandardOutput()
    QString s = Ba
    self.console.append(s)

Comment: Thanks for providing help however your solution does return the same problem

Comment: Maybe there are garbage values with the string,try using built-in string.strip() functionality

Comment: I'm stuck with the same problem.... Got any solution meantime?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the string.rstrip() function instead of string.strip()

Comment: not working either. i don't think the problem is with stripping characters but with the way the process is read and written.
thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

if you change

```
self.console.append(str(self.process.readAllStandardOutput()))
```

to

```
self.console.append(str([self.process.readAllStandardOutput()]))
```

you can see what is going on, hope this helps

Comment: It seems that[PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('')] are added at the end of the textEdit each time i send a command, hence the blank lines appearing.
I'll dig into it. Thanks for the tip ;)

Comment: Actually, i found the solution. I spent so much time but it was so obvious! Shame on me.
The Process is created on def__init.
I deleted it from there and created it in def Send(self):
Now at least everything seem to work the way it should.

Answer (score 0):

```
def appendText(self):
    if self.check1.isChecked():
        TEXT1 = "Dir" + ' ' + str(self.variable.text())
    else:
        TEXT1 = ""
```

you have to remove the last line after else and just type pass
this way no new empty lines will be appended

```
def appendText(self):
    if self.check1.isChecked():
        TEXT1 = "Dir" + ' ' + str(self.variable.text())
    else:
        pass
```